# Tumblr javascript warning / errors

Tags: html, tumblr

I'm terribly sorry for my incompetence, if anyone could help me validate this I would be so thankful.

**Warning**

```
Warning Line 2, Column 653: The language attribute on the script element is obsolete. You can safely omit it.

…/assets/scripts/pre_tumblelog.js?_v=e90984c6ca35aacd4904439beb8bf066"></script>
```

**Errors**

```
Error Line 3, Column 121: Stray doctype.
….0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


Error Line 15, Column 66: Stray start tag html.
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">


Error Line 15, Column 66: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
```

Comment: I revised your question to just the error. Please update it to include the spacing issue when you have a live example and the code to support it.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**

Sadly there is nothing you can do about this error. The error originates from Tumblrs own script:

```
…/assets/scripts/pre_tumblelog.js
```

It is something they would have to fix directly. Maybe message support to give them a heads up.

**Errors**

Without the code, it is a guess. It seems you are missing a `<!doctype>` which is causing errors on the `<html>` tag. Replace with the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-us">
```

You may also have two `<html>` tags, which isn't allowed.

Comment: @EdmondCorcoran I meant update the question with the space issues and relevant code. A live example would be super helpful!